# Can nodemon be used on file relocation (instead of modification)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restart, nodemon, build-tools

I have files in the following folder structure:

[image]

Can I setup Nodemon to restart when `.primary` is moved to another folder (typically a *sibling* folder, at same level)?

Example:

- Move `.primary`:

  - from`app/en_160x600_PROG_RESID_Children`
  - to `app/en_160x600_PROG_TOUR_Baby`.

I've tried multiple variations & attempts with this command, but so far nothing detects the file relocation:

```
nodemon --watch app/**/.primary --exec "brunch watch --server"
```

Comment: Why not just watch `app/`?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but the issue was with the actual filename I was using. Files must have a prefix, can't just start off with a `.` period.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, just figured it out.

Nodemon watches filenames with the specified **extension** (note the strong emphasis on EXTENSION).

While the file I was watching does end with a `primary` extension, it actually MUST have a filename before the period. It cannot simply end with a `.nameOfYourExtension`.

My guess is that internally it must check for `{your-watch-path}/*{your-extension}`, which in my case was: `app/*.primary`, so no wonder I had issues!

After changing my setup to use `focus.primary`, nodemon picks up the file relocation correctly.

[image]